# Ошибка в загрузках шрифта React Native

Tags: javascript, шрифты, react-native

В общем есть вот такой код и суть в том что шрифты все равно не загружаются, частично. Если открыть это в браузере то шрифты работают, но если на телефоне(Android) то вылезает ошибка

```
fontFamily "InterBlack" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.
```

и шрифты соответственно не принимаются. Я не понимаю в чем проблема, на американском форуме решение представлялось тем что функции fonts добавляли асинхронность, но как видно в коде это не помогло, может у вас есть какие идеи, почему это может быть?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

export default function App() {
    const [font, setFont] = useState(false);

    const fonts = async () => await Font.loadAsync({
        InterBlack: require('./assets/fonts/Interblack.ttf')
    });

    if(font) {
        return (
          <View>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Hello</Text>
          </View>

        );
    } else {
        return (
          <AppLoading
            startAsync={fonts}
            onError={err => console.log(err)}
            onFinish={() => setFont(true)}
          />
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text: {
        fontFamily: 'InterBlack'
    }
})
```

Comment: Вдруг кто тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. Помогло то что я все изменения откатил и установку соответственно npm expo-font. Как я сам предполагаю моя ошибка заключалась в том что я устанавливал expo-font через npm, а надо было через expo

Answer (score 1):

Возможная причина: expo-font была установлена через npm, а не через expo

```
expo install expo-font
```

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).